# pgr_dijkstra giving wrong results?

Tags: pgrouting

I'm new to GIS and my SQL knowledge is limited.

I've been working on a project that I was given for my internship. For the project to work, I need to be able to calculate the shortest path from a certain point to another. For this I've created the nodes table which holds the spatial data of nodes and through it I have created the edges table which has

edge_id, source_id, target_id, and distance

as columns. I can confirm that the data on both tables are 100% correct. Now my problem is, I can't get pgr_dijkstra() to work no matter what I do.

What I'm trying to do at the moment is just to see the path from a point to another. From what I learned of some research,

```
 SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra(

    'SELECT edge_id as id,
           source_id as source::int4,
           target_id as target::int4,
           distance as cost::float8
    FROM edges', 1, 85, false,false
);
```

should calculate the shortest path from node 1 to node 85 but the results I get are completely wrong.

I don't know why, and I don't know what to do at this point.

Comment: by 'completely off' you mean 'not the shortest route', but it does find a route? if so...well then your data is still the only culprit I can think of. how did you create both the nodes and edges table exactly? what type of geometries are those edges?

Comment: It does find a route but by connecting nodes that aren't connected. I penta checked the data, it's 100% correct. As for how I created the tables, there's a CAD program that I use (which you've never heard of) on which I draw stuff and it lets me transfer the spatial data of the drawings to a database. I created the tables on the program but it makes zero difference to be honest. I would get the exact same tables if I wrote them myself. Nodes are points and edges are lines that connect the points.

Comment: could you post sample data? or pictures maybe (with node id labels)?

Comment: I am on a different pc now. I'll post tomorrow.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.
  Please do not include statements of urgency (https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3672/should-statements-of-urgency-be-removed-from-questions) or unnecessary thanks in your questions.

Comment: When your data is connected, where it shouldn't be, then you probably chose a too large "snapping" tolerance with `pgr_createTopology`: http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.2/en/src/topology/doc/pgr_createTopology.html
The tolerance value depends on the unit of your projection.